# Problems with iOS reminder notifications behaving inconsistently

Tags: iphone, notifications, ios, reminders

I have a new iPhone 7 and reminders are not acting consistently. Sometimes when a reminder is marked as done it won't be removed from the notifications (remains on lock screen and badge remains on).

Also, as of this morning there are 2 reminders that were set to go off at 7am this morning and didn't, and there are no notifications listed for the reminders. The badges for those reminders do show, and the app does show that there are 2 pending reminders.

The proximity functionality has also seemed to have stopped working for reminders.

The phone is 3-week-old, and the removal of completed reminders from the lock screen was a problem on the old iPhone 6 as well.

Any suggestions for how to remedy this would be greatly appreciated. Alternatively suggestions for a reminder app that is more reliable are also welcome.

Comment: Did you set the new iPhone up as a restore of the old iPhone? If so, try setting it up as a new iPhone with the latest OS.

Comment: We did restore from the old phone. Though we had also tried a factory reset on the old phone and manually added everything into it. That said, the old phone and the new phone were at as high an OS version as was available at any given time. The new phone has 10.2.1

Comment: The geofence feature of Reminders stopped working reliably for me several versions ago. It used to work great under iOS 7. What's strange is other apps that rely on the same geofences work perfectly.

Comment: Same problem here.  I have tried for years to get Reminders to work reliably, but it has always been hit-and-miss for me too.  I'm looking for a way to get Apple's attention about it.  There are definitely problems.